# Android auto pair (bond) Bluetooth (BLE) device with pin code

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth, pairing

I'm trying to pair a Bluetooth (BLE) device without user interaction - meaning that the pairing will be done only programmatically, and the user will not choose Bluetooth device and will not enter the pin code.
I'm using the following code:

```
//request receiver 
IntentFilter pairingRequestFilter = new 
               IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_PAIRING_REQUEST);
pairingRequestFilter.setPriority(IntentFilter.SYSTEM_HIGH_PRIORITY - 1);
this.registerReceiver(mPairingRequestRecevier, pairingRequestFilter);

BluetoothManager bluetoothManager = (BluetoothManager) 
this.getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();
BluetoothDevice mDevice = bluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice("macaddress");
mDevice.setPairingConfirmation(true);
mDevice.setPin("1234".getBytes());
mDevice.createBond();

private final BroadcastReceiver mPairingRequestRecevier = new 
       BroadcastReceiver()
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_PAIRING_REQUEST.equals 
                                         (intent.getAction()))
        {
            final BluetoothDevice device = 
                 intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            int type = 
                  intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_PAIRING_VARIANT, 
                                 BluetoothDevice.ERROR);

            if (type == BluetoothDevice.PAIRING_VARIANT_PIN)
            {
                device.setPin("1234".getBytes());
                abortBroadcast();
            }
            else
            {

            }
        }
    }
};

<!-- permissions -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED" />
```

Few things happened:

1. the app tries to pair the device, but I get a toast message - "can't pair the device try again later".
2. the BroadcastReceiver doesn't get called.

Can someone help me with this issue?